# Initialize multidimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays, initialization

```
 Checkbox[,] checkArray = new Checkbox[2, 3]{{checkbox24,checkboxPref1,null},                                    {checkbox23,checkboxPref2,null}};
```

I am getting error . How do I initialize it?

Comment: What is the error you're getting? The statement looks fine enough on first glance at least...

Comment: field initializer can not reference the non static field, method property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I think I see what's happening here. You're trying to initialize an array at a class level using this syntax, and one of the checkboxes is also a class level variable? Am I correct?

You can't do that. You can only use static variables at that point. You need to move the init code into the constructor.  At the class level do this:

```
 CheckBox[,] checkArray;
```

Then in your constructor:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            checkArray = new CheckBox[2, 3] { { checkbox24,checkboxPref1,null}, {checkbox23,checkboxPref2,null}};
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

int[,] myArray;
myArray = new int[,] {{1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}, {7,8}};

Does for me....

Tony

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see wrong with your code is that it's a CheckBox, not a Checkbox. Capital 'B'.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all of your variables (checkbox24, checkboxPref1, checkbox23, and checkboxPref2) are of type CheckBox

Answer (score 0):

Initialized each element of array in the constructor and it worked. .